# readRSSI not calling didReadRSSI

Tags: ios, objective-c, rssi, cbperipheral

I can't get `didReadRSSI` to call back on my peripheral!!

I'm developing on an **iPad mini - iOS 8.1.2**

I set the peripheral to an `NSMutable` array and I can call connect, disconnect etc. fine from that array so the peripheral object attached to that array is valid.

My code is below, what is wrong? Why don't I get a `didReadRSSI` callback on my peripheral??

```
- (void)updateConnectedRSSITimerFunc {
    for(TheCustomPeripheral *arrayItem in self.peripherals) {
      if(arrayItem.connected) {
          //This is called every 4 seconds from an NSTimer succesfully
          [arrayItem.peripheral readRSSI];
          NSLog(@"RSSI request");
      }
    }
}

-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didReadRSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI error:(NSError *)error {
//This never get's called!!!!!
   NSLog(@"RSSI returned %@", [RSSI stringValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!!!  In the timer I added this... I'm still new to iOS so I missed the delegate bit to get callbacks...

```
            arrayItem.peripheral.delegate = self;
```

As a supplementary question, why do I get this warning?  I'm ignoring it because the app runs fine.

> Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'xxxListTableViewController *const __strong'

Answer:  My class had to be a CBPeripheralDelegate, e.g. @interface myInterface ,CBPeripheralDelegate>